# Find a holomorphic function $f$ on the unit disc, such that $f(1/n) =2^{-n}$ for $n\geq2$, $n\in\mathbb{}$N.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a holomorphic function $f$ on the unit disc, such that $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=2^{-n}$ for $n\geq2$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure this can be done? As best I can tell the Cauchy estimates imply that if $0 \leq f(1/n) \leq 2^{-n}$ for every $n$ then $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: I'm not sure about that.

Comment: In a small nbd of zero, $f(z) = z^{k}h(z)$ for some positive integer $k$ and $h(0) \neq 0$. Put $z=\frac{1}{n}$, we'll get $h(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{n^k}{2^n}$. As $n$ tends to $0$, $h(0)=0$. Contradiction !

Answer (score 2):

$f$ must have a zero at $0$, but is not identically $0$, so it is a zero of some integer order $m$.  Then for some nonzero $c$,  $f(z) = c z^m + O(|z|^{m+1})$ as $z \to 0$.  But that is not the case...