# Find all holomorphic functions satisfying an inequality.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find all holomorphic functions $f$ on $\mathbb{D}$ s.t the following
> condition holds for all $n>1$:$$\left\vert
> f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\right\vert<2^{-n}$$

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093543/find-a-holomorphic-function-f-on-the-unit-disc-such-that-f1-n-2-n-for?noredirect=1&lq=1), but it does not answer this question. I currently have no idea for this problem, except I can show $f(0)=0$. It seems like $f=0$ is the only solution to the problem.
Any help I deeply appreciate!

Comment: If $f$ is not identically zero there exists a potive integer $k$ such that $f(z)=z^{k}g(z)$ with $g$ holomorphic and $g(0) \neq 0$. So $|f(z)| \ge c|z|^{k}$ for some $c >0$ on some disk around $0$.  This contradicts the hypothesis.

Comment: The solutions in the linked question apply directly to your case in exactly the same way.

Comment: @geetha290krm Could you explain why such $c$ exists?

Comment: Because $g$ is continuous and $g(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I still don't get why $g$ is continuous and $g(0)\neq 0$ implies $|g(z)|\geq c$?

Comment: $|g(z)| \geq |g(0)|/2$ for $|z|$ small.